# What is the result limit of Taleo GetAll api

Tags: taleo

Oracle Taleo documentation mentions that for search api, there is limit of 200 results applied by default and if results are more than 200, relationship url will be returned.

I wanted to know if there is any such limit for GetAll api call of objects which don't support search.

Answer (score 1):

Limit is the same for GetAll API